# Why does C++ not have virtual data members?

Tags: c++, virtual

C++ has virtual functions, where invoking one will at runtime look up the function address in a vtable.

C++ also has virtual bases. Accessing a data member of a virtual base will at runtime look up the offset the vtable.

Why does C++ lack virtual data members? Accessing one would look up the offset in the vtable as for a virtual base, but the data member would be provided by a derived

```
virtual void fun();
virtual int val;

void fun() override;
int val override;
```

Comment: How would you override a virtual data member without wasting the storage space of the previous data member?

Comment: It would be wasted, unless declared pure virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Your talk of offsets is an implementation detail.

The content of a virtual function can change in derived instances.

The content of a non-virtual data member can change in derived instances.

A shared data member in the diamond inheritance sense can be implemented via virtual inheritance.

A polymorphic member can be implemented with a virtual accessor.

At best this is syntactic sugar, and not very much of it.

Comment: virtual is just syntactic sugar for function pointers. Virtual data can be faked by virtual accessors, but the cost is running code at runtime. This is different than looking up an offset.